# How to get multilabels accuracy in Tensorfow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am doing a multi label classification using Tensor Flow. When calculate the accuracy I met some problem.
My labels is encoded in one-hot, here is an example:

Suppose `batch_size=2` and there are 3 classes.

```py
label: [[1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]]
logits: [[0.8, 0.2, 0.9],
         [0.8, 0.6, 0.9]]
```

The definition of accuracy is you should predict all the correct labels.
So how to get the accuracy in multi label classification?

Comment: You might want to first define how to convert your logits to your final predicted labels because if I understand correctly the number of true labels varies between examples. Are you always outputing "k" labels (where k is fixed); or you might want to calculate precision and recall @k instead (with varying k, k = 1, 2, 3, ...).  If you always pick top k predicted labels, you can do `tf.nn.top_k` and then compare the predicted labels to the true labels to get the accuracy .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think recall and precision is better than accuracy in multi label. I found `tf.metric.average_precision_at_k`, but how to use it, when I use one-hot code my reuslts are not correct. Could you give a simple example to show hot to use it?